# Error While creating a Project on VSCode

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I have installed Salesforce CLI and then tried to create a Project in VSCode using SFDX: Create Project. But facing the following error. Do I need to install any additional package?

```
ERROR:Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/operators/audit'
    at Function._load (C:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/@salesforce/lazy-require/lib/LazyLoader.js:89:24)
    at require (C:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/rxjs/operators/audit.js:6:10)
    at Module._compile (C:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
12:53:50.590 sfdx force:project:create --projectname VSCodeQuickstart --outputdir c:\Users\Aditya\Desktop --template standard ended with exit code 1
```

Comment: What version are you on? Do you have any CLI plugins installed? You can run `sfdx --version` and `sfdx plugins` in your command line to get that info. You could need to update your CLI with `sfdx update` in the command line.

Comment: It is showing as no plugins installed even after Updating the CLI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching I got to know that there were no plugins installed in the Salesforce CLI

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest
```

I ran the above command in the Command prompt and installed the latest salesforcedx plugins. after this, I was able to create a salesforce project successfully.